[ubuntu 22.04 Geforce 4060Ti]NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is
im here to ask some questions about installing NVIDIA Drivers for NVIDIA Geforce 4060ti(ID:2803, Driver version:535) on Ubuntu22.04 system(uname -r geives 6.5.0-28-generic,and on the same desktop i installed a Window 10), for which i use the command below in the Terminals:
# shut down the secure boot in Bios

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'

as recommended, while recommened command:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic 

fails with :
Package linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic' has no installation candidate

then i install with:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535

and then reboot just to find that nvidia-smi still repoonses with:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

to debug i tried:dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia, which gives me:
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                          535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                   535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                     535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                        535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-535                               535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-535                             535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04                535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.17.1                                       all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               510.47.03-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                              535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                       0.18.2                                         all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535                 535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

notice that while my system is ubuntu22.04, these versions are basically base on ubuntu20.04!
I BELIEVE THIS MIGHT BE MAIN ISSUE WHILE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX IT :(
and i tried inxi -Fxxxrz, it gives me:
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: HP product: Victus by HP 15L Gaming Desktop TG02-2xxx
    v: N/A serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 3
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8B3B v: A (SMVB) serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.21 date: 10/24/2023
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (6-mt/4-st) model: Intel Core i5-14400F bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP smt: enabled arch: N/A rev: 2 cache: L1: 864 KiB L2: 9.5 MiB
    L3: 20 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 886 high: 1160 min/max: 800/4700:3500 cores: 1: 1038
    2: 1113 3: 800 4: 911 5: 800 6: 800 7: 1156 8: 1160 9: 796 10: 800 11: 800
    12: 800 13: 817 14: 800 15: 800 16: 800 bogomips: 79872
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A pcie: speed: 16 GT/s
    lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:2803 class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: nouveau,vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: N/A display-ID: :1
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x2160 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1016x572mm (40.0x22.5")
    s-diag: 1166mm (45.9")
  Monitor-1: default res: 3840x2160 hz: 88 size: N/A
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:7ad0 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:22bd
    class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-28-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtw89_8852be v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:b852 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-14:4 chip-ID: 0bda:b85c class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2 sub-v: 91cb hci-v: 5.2 rev: dfb7
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 28.09 GiB (2.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital
    model: WD PC SN560 SDDPNQE-1T00-2006 size: 953.87 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: HPS1 temp: 36.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 27.99 GiB used: 21.65 GiB (77.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.84 GiB used: 179.2 MiB (9.5%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 64.4 MiB (25.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-4: /home size: 57.23 GiB used: 6.2 GiB (10.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p8
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 61.04 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: 27.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: apt: 2004
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
    2: deb https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
    6: deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zotero.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/zotero-archive-keyring.gpg by-hash=force] https://zotero.retorque.re/file/apt-package-archive ./
Info:
  Processes: 355 Uptime: 11m wakeups: 309 Memory: 15.37 GiB
  used: 3.62 GiB (23.6%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 12.0.1 alt: 11/12 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal
  inxi: 3.3.13

and my gcc version is 12.0.1, other then 12.3.0 from which the DRIVER is COMPILED.
CAN ANYBODY HELP ME OUT? IF ANY EXTRA INFO NEEDED I WOULD RESONSE ASAP.
I LITERALLY SPEND A WHOLE DAY ON INSTALLING THIS.THX IN ADVANCE AND SORRY FOR MY AMATEUR QUESTION AND POOR ENGLISH.
EDIT 1: Thanks to @mikewhatever 's solution, the dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia's reply is now with correct ubuntu0.22.04.1 suffix as below:
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                          535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                   535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                     535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                     535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                     535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                       535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                        535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-535                               535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-535                             535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04                535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.17.1                                       all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               510.47.03-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                              535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                       0.18.2                                         all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535                 535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

then after sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic and reboot, my problem solved! Many thanks to @mikewhatever !

So, something fails, but it is unclear what. Also, what does the following mean: "these versions are basically base on ``ubuntu20.04```"?

@mikewhatever as for what fails when i run sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic， because my system's config language is Chinese, the ERROR info is also Chinese, and i  think changing the language may cause more errors so i didn't post them before. I will change the language and post the English version later. and your latter question is that when run dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia, all terms show up have a ubuntu 20.04 suffix like ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

As for the error, try LANG=C sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic. The output should be in English without a language change. You may want to try and uninstall all Nvidia packages again, then disable "focal/20.04" repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list. After that, reinstall Nvidia packages from "jammy" repositories.

@mikewhatever Thx for your help! I've update the question with English error info from LANG=C sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic, then i tried ur solution, after which dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia gives info with correct ubuntu 22.04 suffix. But after i reboot and run nvidia-smi again the same NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. show up. I also update the question with what dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia gives back. Could you please chk it out?

@mikewhatever Thank you Mike! After commenting I try sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic  again and this time, though i don't know how, it works. After reboot nvidia-smi give me correct info. Thanks to you!
